# How to remove this black spots in texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I have made the model and textured it. I did not get where im getting this black spots on it. I have attach my model.

[image]

[image: rendered model]

Comment: your uv mapping seems to be close to the edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You UV mapping is mapping a transparent part of your texture.

[image]

You can shift it a bit or map it a different way. You can also use another texture for that part of the mesh. There are lot of options to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The cause it that your texture fits the original mesh too precisely and not your subdivided mesh. For a quick fix, you should edit your UV map so that there are some margin between the uv and the texture (make the border of the uv map a little inset than the border of the texture)

If you made your texture by baking, find a method to add a margin.